# How To customise android view pager design

Tags: android, android-fragments

i saw different different design in implemented in apps using view pager i want to customize my view pager looks like  following way .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First you should create a simple layout that has card view. And after implementing the adapter set up view pager in activity.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/card_padding"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The most important thing here is the attribute clipToPadding. When this is false, the ViewPager won’t cut off the views that we want to show partially and the current item will still be centered.

The shadow animation can be implemented using setCardElevation of the CardView with an appropriate factor that depends on the scroll offset.

You can refer the sample: https://github.com/rubensousa/ViewPagerCards/

Hope it helps to you.